# Java - Generating XML for a legacy system

Tags: java, xml, format, legacy

I'm working on an existing system that's generating XML for a legacy system using a simple template language. This is obviously not ideal because it's difficult to see the structure of the generated XML, it suffers from escaping problems and it's easy to generate invalid XML.

For any sane XML formats I'd just Xstream or another Java XML serializing library, but this legacy system has a lot of strange rules like "this node should be excluded if the value is less then ten" and "the formatting of the date in node x depends on the value of node y". There are other strange rules as well, but this should be enough to get the idea.

As I've said, the template approach is far from idea, but it's pragmatic and works (with some effort). Is there a better way to approach generating XML for legacy systems with this amount of formatting rules? XSL has crossed my mind, but implementing any amount of logic in XSL is frankly not very tempting.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need some custom logic during serialization. I am guessing that the in-memory object structure is not directly mirrored in the XML structure? Alternatives:

1. Use StAX and distribute read and write methods within the objects.
2. Use JAXB and insert custom serialization.

Don't even think of expressing your custom logic in anything other than java, i.e. some "super" framework.

Comment: You got it exactly right, the Java classes does not map one-to-one with the XML format and I'm certainly not looking for a super framework :) Although, I'm not too keen on "polluting" the domain model with serialization specific annotations, write methods and what not as it's used for other purposes inside the application.

Comment: If there is only one XML format, then adding read/write logic in the model is okey, keeping object orientation a priority. But you'll be happy to put the logic in reader/writer classes then, same same but different.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if this is what you are looking for, but maybe try XML Binding like JAXB...

In other words: you could generate a class library from your xsd-Schema and then build your object graph in java code, then serialize it in one call to xml.

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple xml and some converters I think:

http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php